# Does R have 'dict' as in python or 'map' as in c++ do?

Tags: r

I am new to R programming. After checking some tutorial I picked up most things I needed, but one thing is still missing: the data structure map.

Does everybody know if R has dict? In which I can store (key, value) pairs?

Thanks!!

Comment: You're getting your Python terms mixed up with C++. *`dict`* is the data structure that stores (key,value) pairs. *`map(somefn,someseq)`* is a function which applies *`somefn`* to every element in *`someseq`*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it does and it is called `list`.

```
> x <- list(a=1, b="foo", c=c(1,1,2,3,5))
> x
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "foo"

$c
[1] 1 1 2 3 5
```

In Python it is called `dict`, for what it's worth.

Comment: There's also a `pairlist` function

Answer (score 5):

Environments are also a candidate, and in many cases the best option.

```
e<-new.env(hash=T)
e$a<-1
e$b<-2

R> e$a
[1] 1
```

The disadvantage of a list is that it is a linear search.

Comment: Does an environment use something better than linear search? And how many members do you need before the linear search performance becomes troublesome, in your experience?

Comment: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/03/lookup-performance-in-r.html
gives a quick overview.  In short if you are looking up by index arrays are the way to go, but if you are going by label hashed environments are better.  There is nothing smaller than 1024, but even then environments are better for label search.  It is probable  that if you have a small lookup table the vector would be better.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [hash](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/index.html) package..

Comment: The hash class provided in the hash packages wraps a hashed environment providing more methods, but also adding a little to overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Since array/vector elements can be named, you get some of the properties of a map/dictionary builtin.

```
x <- c(apple = 1, banana = 99, "oranges and lemons" = 33)
x["apple"]
x[c("bananas", "oranges and lemons")]
x[x == 99]
```

(If your values are of different types, then you need to use a `list` instead of a vector.)

Answer (score 0):

The hash package as aforementioned does add a little overhead but does provide a flexible, intuitive methods for accessing the map/hash/dictionary.  It should be very easy for users from another language to grok it.

A list is the best solution if the list has a small number of elements. (<200 or so).

An environment is best to use if you absolutely cannot tolerate a little overhead AND you do not want the flexible, intuitive methods.

The hash package is the best in most situations.

C-